# How to close database connection?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having a problem in project of mine in VB.NET. The problem is whenever I want to save, delete or update data with an Access database I get an error with a message saying that "not allowed to change the connection string property. connection's current state is open".

I have used `If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close() End If`
command using `finally` in every section where I have called the database.

But still I'm having the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be better if you provided your code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "USING"-Keyword. Exiting a using block calls .Dispose() on the object  which for a SqlConnection will close the connection and any open resources.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connection)

Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * From dbo.table1",connection)

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

EDIT:

```
Module Module1

Public Sub DbConnection()

Dim connectionString as String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourServerAddress;Initial Catalog=university.mdb;
Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Using connection as New Sqlconnection(connectionstring)

Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * From dbo.table1",connection)

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: actually i'm a bit confused can you tell where to write this code. I'm giving you the code where i've created the connection

Comment: Module Module1
    Public inp As String
    Public searchby As String
    Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public Function DbConnection()
        Dim dbProvider As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        Dim dbSource As String
        Dim mydocumentsfolder As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
        Dim thedatabase As String = "/university.mdb"
        Dim fulldatabasepath As String = mydocumentsfolder &thedatabase
        dbSource = "Data Source = " & fulldatabasepath
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        Return con  End Function

Comment: I have edited my post. If it helped you, mark it as done.